# Azure web.config restricting IP Addresses page refresh exception

Tags: php, asp.net, azure, web-config

I'm trying to restrict access to an Azure website to certain IP addresses.
It's mainly a PHP 5.4 site but I've used web.config to allow/restrict access.
Currently it denies everybody except the listed IPs, however, when the page first loads from an allowed IP address it always displays the exception first:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

if the page is then refreshed it delivers the page to the user as normal/expected. The exception seems to happen whenever the browser (Chrome or Firefox) is first opened or when the web page is closed and then visited again after a long gap.

The web.config is in the root directory and there is no other authentication as yet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <security>
   <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
     <clear/>
     <add allowed="true" ipAddress="XX.XX.XXX.XXX" />
    </ipSecurity>
   </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure support got back to me and said it was a bug that would be fixed in a future update.

> However, there is also a fix -> switching the site to be in 'Always On' mode

This requires that the site is up using the basic / standard tiers i.e. you can't use 'always on' in the free tier.

Well, hopefully you can still get it to work using the free tier... once they fix the bug  :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your `Web.config` file. What's probably happening is that the browser is caching the home page. So when you refresh the page it loads correctly.

Comment: I tried adding a no caching header, but I'm still getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This part is now configurable in the cloud service configuration file (.cscfg).

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
    <AccessControls>
        <AccessControl name="test">
            <Rule action="permit" description="test" order="100" remoteSubnet="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32" />
            <Rule action="deny" description="test" order="200" remoteSubnet="0.0.0.0/0" />
        </AccessControl>
    </AccessControls>
    <EndpointAcls>
        <EndpointAcl role="WebRoleName" endPoint="Endpoint1" accessControl="test" />
    </EndpointAcls>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

First add the IP-adresses that you want to permit and then deny all others.
In the *EndpointAcls* we specify our endpoints that is listed in the *ServiceDefinition.csdef* file. And connect the endpoint to the newly created AccessControl.